# Can't save an object inside a ModelFormSetView in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, formset

I'm working with a ModelFormSetView from django-extra-views, but am unable to save an object of the model that the ModelFormSet is based

```
class StudentEnrolInClassView(SuccessMessageMixin, ModelFormSetView):
     model = StudentApplication
     ...

     def formset_valid(self, formset):
        for student_application in formset.cleaned_data:
            if student_application['school_class']:
                appl = student_application['id']
                student = Student()
                ...
                student.save()
                enrolment = Enrolment(student=student, school_class=student_application['school_class'])
                enrolment.save()
                appl.approved = datetime.datetime.now()
                appl.student = student
                appl.save()  # THIS ISN'T SAVING!
        return super(StudentEnrolInClassView, self).formset_valid(formset)
```

The newly created student and enrolment objects save correctly, but the pre-existing (and updated) appl doesn't save, but doesn't throw any error or warning. I've tried getting a new instance of it from the DB using:

```
appl = StudentApplication.objects.get(id=student_application['id'].id)
```

but this didn't have any effect.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I discovered the problem was in the call to the super formset_valid() function at the end. formset_valid() in a ModelFormSetView saves the objects of the formset. In this case, as the original objects are only for viewing (not editing), it saves the original objects, which were unmodified *after* it has save the modified objects in my view. So the above code was saving correctly, just those objects we being over-written with the original objects shortly thereafter. The problem was solved by replacing

```
return super(StudentEnrolInClassView, self).formset_valid(formset)
```

with

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```